# RLIMIT_STACK inclusive of environment variables and command line arguments or exclusive

Tags: c, linux, stack, environment-variables, virtual-memory

I understand that, environment variables and command line arguments are stored towards the top of the stack. I have verified that by printing the address of argv and env as well.

I also understand that there is a limit on the size of the stack for a process, which we can print using `ulimit -s` or using `getrlimit` function with `RLIMIT_STACK` as the first argument.

But some texts show environment variables and command line arguments as if they are stored in some separate parts of the virtual memory layout.

My question is: Whether the limit on stack applies to the actual program stack exclusive of environment variables and command line arguments or inclusive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is answered in the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit):

```
RLIMIT_STACK
...
    Since Linux 2.6.23, this limit also determines the amount of space used for the
    process's  command-line arguments and environment variables.
```

Comment: Attempting to set `rlimit_stack` after [Stack Clash](http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2017/06/19/1) remediations may result in failure or related problems. Also see Red Hat [Issue 1463241](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1463241)